# Highcharts: how to make slices readjust when disabling one?

Tags: highcharts, legend, pie-chart, slice, adjustable

Is this possible? I want the other slices in the pie chart to adjust to a full circle when one is disabled in the legend, rather than just making an empty slice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the behavior of the `legendItemClick` event handler you can remove the sector instead of hiding it.

```
    pie: {
         point: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (eventArgs) {
                    this.remove(); // Remove the point
                    eventArgs.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default behavior
                }
            }
        },
        showInLegend: true
    }
```

This will only get you half the way though. The problem is that you cannot get the point back since it will be removed from the legend as well.

A way to get around this would be to add a reset button that brings back the original data set with `series.setData()`. See this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PrnfT/).

Comment: Thanks, works for me, now I just have to figure out how to call that setData() function from within the php wrapper I'm using for Highcharts...